# Introducing arguments/args to a subprocess on a sh bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnupg, args

Let's say I am creating a sh script to auto the trust of keys

```
$masterkey = 0x36879494
gpg --edit-key $masterkey
```

then I need to pass the next instructions to the subcommand gpg

```
fpr && trust && 5 && y && q
```

However the machine does not understand this makes part of a gpg instruction set instead of a general bash instruction. I tried with <, --args=, --gpg-args=, echo; but nothing worked. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: wrap that in dbl-quotes? (or single-quotes). Else be more specific about what you have tried. Good luck.

Comment: Even if you could send keystrokes to simulate going through an interactive prompt, not a good idea because if your distro does some kind of upgrades, program upgrades, and those menu options change even by one character then your program breaks, but you won't even realize it wont work from reading your script, only until you actually run it and it fails. Were you trying to apply some key specification? Have you checked the man or info pages, are you sure there isn't a command line option sequence that can do the same?

Comment: @shellter yes, I also tried dbl-quotes, but nothing :( Thank you

Comment: @user454038 you are right ! :D there is a command --interactive that works, nevertheless I continue being stuck because I don't know how to concatenate the instructions. I tried with &&, commas, | as well as with and without () and double quotes but nothing worked either.

Comment: `gpg --edit-key 0x36879494 --interactive trust ` works but how to 
`gpg --edit-key 0x36879494 --interactive "fpr && trust && 5 && y && q"` ?

Comment: Semicolons? Literal newlines (i.e. `$'fpr\ntrust\n5\ny\nq'`)? Feed input from a pipe/heredoc?

Comment: @EtanReisner Great suggestions, thank you. I tried all of them, with none, simple and double quoutes, not achieving the expected result. Trying this `gpg --edit-key 0x36879494 --interactive fpr --interactive trust --interactive 5 --interactive y --interactive q` it stops at the third arg `5`.

Comment: `--interactive` doesn't mean "take the next argument as a command string. It means "run interactively and ask for confirmation". I actually think you *don't* want it for this. And notice that I used `$'...'` quoting for the literal newlines case. That's **not** single quoting. That's bash [ANSI C](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) quoting. Show the other attempts you made?